# To prove $f$ is Injective where $f$ satisfies $f\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}+y\right)=1+f(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> > Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $f\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}+y\right)=1+f(y)$. Find all such functions.

My try:

Plug $x=y=1$ and assume $f(1)=k$, we get
$$f(k+1)=k+1$$
Now assuming $f$ is injective, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
f\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}+y\right) & =f\left(\frac{f(y)}{y}+y\right)=1+f(y) \\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{f(x)}{x} & =\frac{f(y)}{y} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{f(1)}{1}=\frac{f(k+1)}{k+1} \Rightarrow k(k+1)=k+1 \Rightarrow k=1
\end{aligned}$$
Thus $f(x)=x$. But what is left is to prove $f$ is Injective a Priori.

Comment: Note that this is from Vietnam National Olympiad 2022, some solutions here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2794225p24588829 and https://calimath.org/pdf/VNO2022-2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

We have $f(nf(1)+y) = n + f(y) > n$, for every $y > 0, n \ge 1$. Hence $\lim_{y \to +\infty} f(y) = +\infty$. If there exists $x_1 \ne x_2$ such that $a_1 := f(x_1)/x_1 > a_2 := f(x_2)/x_2$, then, for every $y > 0$, $f(a_1 + y) = f(a_2 + y)$. This means $f$ is periodic. Indeed, for every $n$, $f(a_2 + n(a_1 - a_2)) = f(a_1 + (n-1)(a_1-a_2)) = f(a_2 + (n-1)(a_1-a_2))$. This is a contradiction. Hence there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(x) = cx$ for every $x > 0$. The rest of the argument is easy.

Comment: Why $f\left(a_1+(n-1)\left(a_1-a_2\right)\right)=f\left(a_2+(n-1)\left(a_1-a_2\right)\right)$ a contradiction?

Comment: $f(a_2 + n(a_1 - a_2)) = f(a_2 + (n-1)(a_1 - a_2))$ for every $n$, hence, $f(a_1) = f(2a_1-3a_2) = f(3a_1-4a_2) = \cdots$. and $\lim_{n \to \infty} na_1 - (n+1)a_2 = +\infty$.

Comment: How do you obtain $f(nf(1)+y) = n + f(y) > n$, for every $y > 0, n \ge 1$

Comment: Because $f(x) > 0$ for every $x > 0$

Comment: @KazukiOKAMURA that was the inequality part. I was wondering about the equality

Comment: We have $f(f(1)+y) = 1+f(y)$ for $y > 0$. Then, let $y = z + f(1)$ for $z > 0$ and we have $f(2f(1)+z) = 1+f(z+f(1)) = 1 + (1+f(z)) = 2 + f(z)$. Repeat this argument.